# Haskell Inserstion sort count

Tags: sorting, haskell, monads, counting

My problem is to turn this:

```
 iSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
 iSort [] = []
 iSort (x:xs) = ins x (iSort xs)

 ins x [] = [x]
 ins x (y:ys)
   | x <= y    = x : y : ys
   | otherwise = y : ins x ys
```

Into a solution that keeps track of the number of times it makes a comparison, here a skeleton of the code I need to produce:

```
 iSortCount :: Ord a => [a] -> (Integer, [a])
 iSortCount [] = ...
 iSortCount (x:xs) = ...

 insCount x (k, [])     = ... 
 insCount x (k, (y:ys)) -- Count the times when it reach's here     
   | x <= y    =  ...
   | otherwise = ...
   where ...
```

I've tried a lot of things from using lets, wheres, writer monad, making my own type, the state monad, and I seem to just be over looking something because I keep running into the problem with "y : ins x ys" because what that function returns should be (Int, [a]) and : does not work on a tuple. I tried to split it up to do something like this

```
do
(a,b) <- ins x (k+1, ys)
return (k, (y : b))
```

but it seems to not think that ins returns a tuple when it did in that version so it just wasn't pattern matching on it i guess. My main question is where I should look now? I worked on this for a long time and this problem is starting to frustrate me cause it look so easy...

Answer with Ezra help:

```
iSort' [] = []
iSort' (x:xs) = ins' x (iSort' xs)

ins' x [] = [x]
ins' (x,i) (y:ys)
    | x <= fst y = (x,i+1) : y : ys
    | otherwise  =     y : ins' (x,i+1) ys

countInsertions x = sum $ map snd $ iSort' $ zip x $ repeat 0
```

Comment: An MVar springs to mind, but that seems like a kludge. I'm curious what others will say.

Comment: Can't you just write a function `cmp x y = {-# SCC "cmp" #-} (x <= y)`, use `cmp` instead of `<=` and ghc's profiling?  Or do you actually need the number of comparisons available in the program instead of just as a result of analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach would to just add an accumulator to the solution that you already have:

```
iSort' [] = []
iSort' (x:xs) = ins' x (iSort' xs)

ins' x [] = [x]
ins' (x,i) (y:ys)
    | x <= fst y = (x,i) : y : ys
    | otherwise  =     y : ins' (x,i+1) ys

countInsertions x = sum $ map snd $ iSort' $ zip x $ repeat 1
```

This solution has the benefit of being familiar.  I just replaced each item in the list with a tuple representing the item and the number of times it's been shuffled.  They're initialized to `1` because I count everything as having been shuffled at least once.

The sort routine is largely the same, but a "setup" function is now needed, so you won't want to provide the list of tuples, but the list of items.  Since it's the second item in the tuple, we need `snd`, and since we want the total we use `sum`.

Comment: I also tried something similar to this but didn't think about making the counter with x. Plus you did it with out monads which is what I was trying to do before converting it into a monadic function. Thank you for your response.

Comment: I had to do a little change to your code to produce what I was aiming for but its a small change. I needed to make it count the number of times it made a comparison so [1,2,3,4,5] would be 4. 1 checks 2, 2 check 3 etc. So heres the update and thanks for your answer.

"Edit" Put answer in my original post because comments dont let code indention. Hopefully Ill reach a monadic answer soon.

Answer (score 10):

Conversion of pure code to monadic code can be tricky, hopefully these tips can give you the right idea:

- Pick a monad. You could also use writer on the Sum monoid, but you may find the state-based code more straight-forward.
- Consider all of the expressions in your code: which expressions could cause the state variable to increment? `ins` makes a comparison, but more subtly, because the recursive call to `iSort` could call `ins`, it also one of these expressions you'll have to keep in mind.
- Remember that the idea behind a monad is to hide the plumbing of passing the count behind the scenes. So the wrapped return types of your functions don’t change; they just grow a monadic skin which you can use `>>=` to get them out.
- Recall all of the expressions that could cause the state variable to increment: those are your monadic calls. Rewrite them into `tempVar <- ins foo` form inside a do-block, and replace the old locations with the temporary variables you allocated.
- Use your monad! Float your guard into an inner case statement, and before performing the case-match, increment the state variable.

And that should do it!

There's also an evil way to do it, which involves `unsafePerformIO`.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like the perfect job for the writer monad. See http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#writer

Comment: That was my first thought too, but I was just having problems with incrementing the log (the count), I was trying to use tell in a do notation, "tell (+1)" but Im pretty sure I miss read or understood how to use tell. It seemed tell effected the log but since on learnyouahaskell it usually only has the log as a [String]

Comment: Int does not have a monoid defined for it; you'll have to use "Sum Int" instead. Fortunately, as long as you arrange your types correctly, `tell 1` will do what you want! (Because `Sum` has a `Num` instance).

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
import Control.Monad.State

type Counter = State Int

incr :: Counter ()
incr = modify (+1)

ins :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> Counter a
ins x [] = return [x]
ins x (y:ys)
  | x <= y    = incr >> return $ x : y : ys
  | otherwise = incr >> ins x ys >>= (y :)

iSort :: Ord a => [a] -> Counter [a]
iSort [] = return []
iSort (x:xs) = iSort xs >>= ins x

cSort :: Ord a => [a] -> ([a],Int)
cSort = flip runState 0
```

But please notice, that this is rather inefficient.

Comment: Not quite correct: if he's counting comparisons the otherwise case of `ins` should also increment.

Comment: @Edward Z. Yang Yes. Actually it should. But how about the case in `iSort`, it's also a comparison, thus worth mentioning.

Comment: Mmm, I don't think so: pattern-matching on a cons-cell is different from calling `<=`, the latter of which is what I think is being counted.